# Why the threads are not released after all work is consumed from python Queue

Tags: python, multithreading

I use `Queue` to provide tasks that threads can work on. After all work is done from `Queue`, I see the threads are still alive while I expected them being released. Here is my code. You can see the active threads number is increasing after a batch of task(in the same queue) increases from the console. How could I release the threads after a batch of work get done?

```
import threading
import time
from Queue import Queue

class ThreadWorker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, task_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            work = self.task_queue.get()
            #do some work
            # do_work(work)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.task_queue.task_done()

def get_batch_work_done(works):
    task_queue =  Queue()
    for _ in range(5):
        t = ThreadWorker(task_queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()
    for work in range(works):
       task_queue.put(work)
    task_queue.join()
    print 'get batch work done'
    print 'active threads count is {}'.format(threading.activeCount())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for work_number in range(3):
        print 'start with {}'.format(work_number)
        get_batch_work_done(work_number)
```

[image]

Comment: That code isn't working for me (assumed py27), threads get stuck at `while True` loop.

Comment: That's the problem. The `run()` method needs to be able to quit otherwise the thread it's in will continue to run.

Comment: @valtuarte just updated the code indention,should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a non blocking read in a loop and use the exception handling to terminate

```
def run(self):
      try:            
        while True:            
          work = self.task_queue.get(True, 0.1)
        #do some work
        # do_work(work)
      except Queue.Empty:
        print "goodbye"
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps me figured it out.